# INSERT запрос без VALUES

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Привет всем. Вот вопрос, который я имел в виду (не для `SET`):

Есть запрос такой:

```php
mysqli_query($dataBase, "INSERT INTO `Users` VALUES ('','$email','$name','$pass','$gend','$startImg');");
```

Который хотелось бы записать примерно так:

```
INSERT INTO `Users` VALUES `id` = 2, `email` = '$email', `nickname` = '$name';
```

Как это сделать правильно. PDO желания использовать нет (имеенованые плейсхолдеры).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT 
INTO `Users` 
SET `id` = 2, `email` = '$email', `nickname` = '$name';
```

Ссылка на [документацию](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html), второй вариант синтаксиса.

Comment: Спасибо. Затупил.